# Which HTTP tool is more accurate?

Tags: http, header, gzip

I try to use mod_deflate for compress and my hosting is gkg.net. I test my site with different HTTP header tools to be sure if compress is on.

I couldn't see "content-encoding:gzip" at response header data at Chrome page speed, Firefox Firebug and live HTTP headers add-on Firefox. But, some tools show it working like: http://web-sniffer.net/ and pingdom.

Support people of gkg.net says compress enabled and my site is gzipped.
my test url is: http://mavitasarim.net/TEST6/index.html

I have two questions:

1. is my test url gzipped really?
2. which tool results are more accurate, or why is there difference between different tools' outputs?

Answer (score 0):

The user agent and web server negotiate the content encoding. The web server can only use gzip encoding if the user agent lists that accepts gzip encoding. If the user agent doesn't list gzip support then the web server won't compress the page.

When I loaded your page in Chrome, my browser sent this header:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
```

Your web server sent this response header, indicating that the page is indeed compressed:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Comment: Hi John, Thanks you very much for your quick response. which tool did you see "Content-Encoding: gzip" at? I also use chrome page speed addon.   I couldn't see it.    do you have any suggestion to be able see it? regards